# What to do if Visual Studio does only show greyed out options at project > store?

Tags: visual-studio, deployment, visual-studio-cordova, windows-store

I can no longer deploy my cordova app (W10 UWP for W10 desktop and W10 (m) to the windows store using Visual Studio 2017 (Community). What should I do?

I have a app based on cordova in Visual Studio 2017 (Community) which is already in the store and working fine. I used "Project > Store > Create app packages" and it worked great before.

The problem is that since a couple of weeks/months that option (and everything else but "Open developer account" and "Access developer licence") is greyed out. I can click on those two but one only brings me to the normal developer options of Windows 10 and the second one opens a firefox window with this link (https://appdev.microsoft.com/StorePortals/de-de/account/signup/start) for me which tells me there is a security problem. If I open it in Edge it works, but it is not helping at all.

I can build my code and test it on my devices (PC and smartphone) and it works just fine.

Any idea what I need to do to get the option to deploy to the store / create appxbundle files to put them in the store again?

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft stopped supporting cordova directly in Visual Studio to push their other mobile product.  Hence, you can't deploy to Windows Store.  To be honest, the Windows Store is useless.  Try Electron in Cordova and deploy as a PWA instead.